# Caixa de Seleção(Formulário) - Copiar para linha abaixo e alterar vínculo de célula

Tags: excel-vba, macro

Olá!

Gostaria de saber se é possível realizar o seguinte:

Possuo diversas caixas de seleção, onde cada uma é vinculada a célula em que está, ao selecionar a célula dessa caixa e arrastar para baixo, copiando a fórmula que contem na célula e a própria caixa, o vínculo da célula continua o mesmo da caixa acima.

É possível fazer com que o vínculo da célula altere juntamente ao arrastar a célula para baixo?

Exemplo:

Célula AG15 possui a caixa de seleção, e a caixa está vinculada a esta célula, onde na célula contém a seguinte fórmula:

> =SE(AG15=VERDADEIRO;1;0)

Assim ao realizar a seleção da célula e arrastar para baixo a fórmula muda para a seguinte:

> =SE(AG16=VERDADEIRO;1;0)

Ficando a fórmula da maneira correta e somente o vínculo da célula na caixa de seleção permanece na célula AG15 porém gostaria que alterasse automaticamente para a célula AG16 igualmente faz na fórmula.

Tem como realizar o procedimento de alguma forma?

Comment: fixe as células primárias utilizando o $ por exemplo $AG16

Comment: Bom dia Lucas!
Mesmo que eu fixe a célula primária no caso a coluna "AG" a linha não se altera, quando é copiado/arrastado (alça de preenchimento) a célula que contém a caixa de seleção, a célula vinculada se mantém.